# Composer - Class Not Found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I'm still having problems getting composer to work.  When not using composer autoloading, I can require_once the class file and instantiate an object.  However, when attempting to use autoloading, I receive this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MyCompany\User' not found in /var/www/html/portal/login.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/portal/login.php on line 7
```

login.php looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use MyCompany\User;

$user = new User();
```

The current composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "MyCompany\\User\\": "vendor/mycompany/user/"
        }
  },
  "require": {
    "mycompany/user": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "packagist.org": false
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "version": "master",
      "url": "git@mysrc.example.com:/opt/git/phplib/classes/User.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

The User.php file is this:

```
<?php

namespace mycompany;

class User {

function __construct() {
  print "composer has done something\n";
}

} //end class User

?>
```

Finally, folder structure is:

```
portal\
  composer.json
  login.php
  vendor\
       mycompany\
             \user\User.php
             \pdo\PDO.php
             \page\Page.php
```

Somehow namespacing seems to be the underlying issue but I'm not sure how to set it up in order to support this structure.  Ultimately, even if the namespace is "mycompany" that would be fine but no combinations of namespace in the class, composer.json autoload statement, and use statement have worked.  I have looked through countless questions here and none seem to match this exact scenario.  This is on a linux system and I have also tried various combinations of upper and lower case for files and folders, though some fail because composer won't allow uppercase in certain areas.

Comment: If your code is a composer package, you should have a `composer.json` file within `mycompany` that does this automatically.

Comment: What is the "this" that you're referring to?  There is a composer.json associated with the repository for the User class but I'm not seeing how that will fix the issue at the higher level.  It's still not working.  Here is the composer.json associated with the User class found in mycompany above.  ``` {
  "name": "mycompany/user",
  "description": "Base user class"
}
```

Comment: Why did you import the class using the mixed-cased namespace `MyCompany` while the class is using the lower-cased namespace `mycompany`? Also, why did you add the namespace `MyCompany\User` to the PSR4 configuration while using the namespace `mycompany`resp. `MyCompany` (without `User`) for your classes?

Comment: Your package's `composer.json` should have an `autoload` section, rather than having to add each one to your project's configuration. But I agree with Nico that you should resolve the case mismatch before you do anything else.